# Would it be appropriate to inspect the mean inter-item correlation for an ordinal scale?

Tags: r, correlation, survey, ordinal-data, research-design

I'm analyzing the data from a questionnaire using ordinal scales with five response options (Strongly Agree to Strongly Disagree).

I'm conducting my analysis using R, and have recoded the item response options themselves. Would it be meaningful to inspect the mean/average inter-item correlation of the items?

I'm getting a value of .25, which is in the acceptable range, but not sure how much caution to use when interpreting this value.